# hide&show toggle and class change multiply divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking on stackoverflow for a solution but I didn't find it. My problem is that I make a spoiler on my website and it slide toggled good but I want when it slides that it change class and back to current class. but i make multiple divs with same class I don't want, when I click on the different spoiler that all the spoilers will open and changes classes.

```
<a class="show-hide" data-divId="stats1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<div class="spoiler-kop1">
    <span class="toer-kop-text">Toernooi 1</span>
</div>
</a>
<div class="spoiler-img">
    <div class="toernooi-info">
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Start datum:</td>
            <td>30-10-2013</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eind datum: </td>
            <td>30-10-2013</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Eind datum: </td>
            <td>30-10-2013</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Teams:</td>
            <td> TCA , Curse , TSM , TGA<br/> RC , DHD , DDG , DODO </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Type: </td>
            <td>2 vs 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Map:</td>
            <td>Howeling Abyss</td>
          </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
    <a class="toernooi-img" href="../classes/fancybox/images/1-big.png"><img src="../classes/fancybox/images/1-small.png" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

and here is Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-hide').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-hide').click(function() {
        var $this = $( this );
        $this.removeClass( 'show-hide' ).addClass( 'someNewClass' );
        $this.next( 'div' ).slideToggle( 'slow', function() {
            $this.removeClass( 'someNewClass' ).addClass( 'show-hide' );
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function supports callback after animation complete.

Comment: hello @antyrat, thank you for response but it works almost. when the animation is going he changing the class but when it stops he falls back into the old class. and back also what can i do/

Comment: @user2929609 So you don't want old class back? Can you be more specific? Can't understand fully what you want from your English